# After R Studio launches how to auto load a file for editing

Tags: rstudio

When rStudio is launched, by default it has scripts open in the editor which a user was working on in last launch. 
I want to change this default behavior and want rStudio to open a given script (present in rStudio workspace) after startup for editing.

To elaborate:
I open a rStudio and created a script A, B and C. Save all three. Exit rStudio while the scripts are still open in editor.
When I re login to rStudio, I can see all the three script A,B and C in the editor tabs. 
Now, I close all the files in the editor and exit rStudio.
After this if I login, after startup, I will not find any files in the editor.

As per my requirement I want to configure it to always open say A file in editor after the rStudio startup, no matter what the user was working on earlier.

How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding a re-load of A,B & C is easy - click 'Tools/Global Options...' and uncheck the 'Restore previously open..' checkbox:
[image]

There's currently no similar GUI for specifying a startup document. One way to achieve this programmatically is to add this code to your `.Rprofile`:

```r
setHook("rstudio.sessionInit", function(newSession) {
  rstudioapi::navigateToFile("[your script path here]")
}, action = "append")
```